# How can I use screen time api in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, react-native

I want to implement a feature in iOS where I can see all the installed Apps in my app and see its usage time. Also, I should be able to block the user to use particular apps if they have exceeded certain amount of time in any other app. Is there a way which I can use to implement this?

I tried using screen-time-api-ios from pub.dev but was not able to acheive that. Also, I tried some other methods which I found on the internet but those seemed to be outdated

Comment: For privacy reasons your app cannot obtain a list of apps that are installed nor the time spent on them. The api that provides the ability to set activity limits is [DeviceActivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeviceActivity)

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi! On Android can we achieve that feature?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about Android.